# In Java, is there a deadlock if `insert()` and `size()` executed in concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

The codes looks like this ([link](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/pb7con/code/ThreadsLocks/LinkedList/src/main/java/com/paulbutcher/ConcurrentSortedList.java)):

```
/***
 * Excerpted from "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks",
***/
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class ConcurrentSortedList {

  private class Node {
    int value;
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    Node() {}

    Node(int value, Node prev, Node next) {
      this.value = value; this.prev = prev; this.next = next;
    }
  }

  private final Node head;
  private final Node tail;

  public ConcurrentSortedList() {
    head = new Node(); tail = new Node();
    head.next = tail; tail.prev = head;
  }

  public void insert(int value) {
    Node current = head;
    current.lock.lock(); 
    Node next = current.next;
    try {
      while (true) {
        next.lock.lock(); 
        try {
          if (next == tail || next.value < value) { 
            Node node = new Node(value, current, next); 
            next.prev = node;
            current.next = node;
            return; 
          }
        } finally { current.lock.unlock(); } 
        current = next;
        next = current.next;
      }
    } finally { next.lock.unlock(); } 
  }

  public int size() {
    Node current = tail;
    int count = 0;

    while (current.prev != head) {
      ReentrantLock lock = current.lock;
      lock.lock();
      try {
        ++count;
        current = current.prev;
      } finally { lock.unlock(); }
    }

    return count;
  }

}
```

It says it uses a **hand-over-hand locking**. `insert()` get lock from list head to list tail, and `size()` get lock from list tail to list head. `size()` and `insert()` can be executed in concurrency.

But I think `size()` and `insert()` cannot be executed in concurrency. Because if `insert` is holding the lock on `aNode` and request the lock on `aNode.next`, while `size` is holding the lock on `aNode.next` and request the lock on `aNode`, there will be a deadlock.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.. `size()` will release current lock before it requests a new lock.. So there will be no deadlock..

Comment: A more explicit way of saying that:  The size() method never locks more than one lock at the same time.  Deadlock won't occur unless at least two threads each try to lock more than one lock.